# Usar onclick e ontouchstart

Tags: jquery, onclick

Tenho essa div:

```
<div onclick="funcao('')">
```

E em Iphone (principalmente o 6) o onclick não roda muito bem. Vi que o ideal é usar o **ontouchstart**, mas quando coloco os dois da erro, pois ele acha que foi clicado 2 vezes.

O que fazer?

Comment: Com que você quer dizer com o "não rodar muito bem"?

Comment: Tem hora que ele pega o onclick, tem hora que não....

Answer (score 3):

O que eu costumo fazer é assim:

```
var appEvents = {
    down: 'ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchstart' : 'click' /* ou mousedown */,
    move: 'ontouchmove' in window ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove',
    up: 'ontouchend' in window ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup'
    // e outros que precises
}
```

e depois uso

```
el.addEventListener(appEvents.down, function(){
```

assim ele detecta se está em ambiente browser e usa o `click` ou ambiente móvel e usa o `touchstart`

Comment: Valeu Sergio, é que o site já esta rolando, e ta tudo inline o onclick....

Eu teria que ver uma forma de alterar todos o onclick para ontouchstart